# laravel 4 restful controller wont work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I am trying to make the laravel 4 controller in mac terminal by

```
 php artisan controller:make UserController
```

It work's and insert the controller in the folder.

In my route.php i add:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

In my UserController in index i make

```
return "Hello world"
```

But when i am entering localhost/users it don't show anything, either in /users/create.

What can i do?

Trace errors:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
open: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/salety/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
 * @param  Exception  $e
 * @return void
 */
protected function handleRoutingException(\Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ResourceNotFoundException)
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage());
    }
```

UserController

```
 <?php

 class UserController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return "Hello world!";
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}

}
```

Comment: What exactly does your controller look like? Does it come up if you add /index?

Comment: No, already tried that also. Check post to see the controller

Answer (score 2):

You need to change Index to getIndex when using RESTful controllers.

Comment: Ok, also create and what about the others?

Comment: I think you may be trying to create a resource controller. In that case in your routes you would use Route::resource instead of Route::controller. When using controller you need to specify get and post for each function.

Answer (score 2):

What you've created using the artisan command is a [resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

To get this to work, change your routes.php file to this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

This will make the /users route a resource and allow it to respond properly.

Be sure to look at the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) on resource controllers and be sure to pay attention to the **Actions Handled By Resource Controller** section, as this gives you the key to what methods are used for which URI's.

Answer (score 1):

Well for restfull controllers you need to use this form getIndex , getCreate , postRegister..etc , you can either use Route::controller() or Route::resource()

Answer (score 0):

after changing stuff in your routes.php you need to run

```
php composer dump-autoload
```

to refresh the autoloading files with edited routes.